# Dados do twitter com python

Tags: python

Olá. Quero minerar dados do twitter usando python. Comecei fazendo um exemplo inicial, mas está dando erro.

Importei o twitter_python para a pasta lib do python 3.6 através do comando setupe.py install no prompt do windows. O código:

```
import twitter  
api=twitter.Api()  

statuses=api.GetPublicTimeline()  

print(s.user.name for s in statuses)
```

Segue o erro
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/erro-jpg--521

segue a pasta site package:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/estruturas_da_pasta_site_package-jpg

Comment: Adiciona o stacktrace completo do erro em vez uma screenshot da tela.

Comment: O erro que deu de identificar é que está faltando o módulo requests.. tenta dá um : ```pip install requests```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, o erro ocorre pois você está fazendo uma requisição sem ter a library requests instaladas, se você usa o python3, digite esse comando no terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install requests
```

Comment: existe incompatibilidade entre versões? Versão do python (3.6) e python-twitter (acho que é a versão 3. alguma coisa). Não lembro a versão e ainda não testei a sua resposta porque estou num computador que não tem o projeto que estou estudando. Provavelmente amanhã eu faço as mudanças na instalação da biblioteca.